# Getting out of a table

Tags: table

Have been trying various ways to insert two tables, but having no success getting the cursor out of the first table.  This means that the second table gets inserted in the last cell of the first table.

```
(table-insert 15 3 5 1)
(table-insert-sequence "1" 15 1 1 'center)
(table-goto-bottom-right-corner)

(insert "\n")

(table-insert 16 3 5 1)
(table-insert-sequence "16" 16 1 1 'center)
(table-goto-bottom-right-corner)
```

Comment: Use `(next-line)` instead of `(insert "\n")`.

Comment: Is it correct to go to the bottom right corner first?

Comment: Why ask? Try it with and without it and see what happens.

Comment: You sound like a politician !  Are you Bill Clinton by any chance ?

Comment: No, I'm just pointing out that you can get answers to these questions yourself - you don't need to ask here.

Comment: Perhaps there is a more appropriate call, as I would not like my code to look like cow crap.

Comment: Figure out what works first, before making aesthetic judgements.

Answer (score 1):

From the thoughts of @NickD, the solution is that after moving to the bottom right corner of the table, one calls `(next-line)`.